# Как визуально выделить определенный айтем ListView

Tags: android, listview

Хочу сделать список, прокручивая который, элементы становились в определенную позицию и текст этих элементов становился больше и его можно было редактировать.

Список должен выглядеть примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работать должен как:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е.
пользователь прокручивает наш список(как на первом срине) и во второй позиции выделяется попавший туда элемент списка(выделяется, например, другим фонов и больше текстом).

и нужно, чтобы элемент попавший во вторую позицию, можно было отредактировать текст в нем.

и все это должно быть так же плавно как на втором скрине..

Подскажите, как можно реализовать подобное ?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

**Правка:**

Спасибо за внимание

Вопрос вышел обширным изначально потому что хотел показать, что я вообще хочу сделать в итоге для того, чтобы изначально выбрать корректный и оптимальный путь решения задачи.

Более конкретный вопрос:
как в лист вью сделать выделения какого-то конкретного элемента(например второго сверху) другим размером шрифта ? При этом, при прокручивании списка, элемент, который попадет на второе место - должен изменить размер шрифта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы определенным айтемам списка задать различный вид необходимо создать, собственно, саму разметку для каждого вида айтема - как они будут выглядеть и в адаптере переопределить два метода:

`getItemViewType(position)` - содержит условие, по которому можно определить, айтем какого вида выводить в текущюю позицию. Возвращает идентификатор этого айтема.

`getViewTypeCount()` - возвращает количество айтемов разного вида.

Создадим простой список с двумя видами айтемов: `item_normal.xml` - общий вид и `item_big.xml` - вид с увеличенным шрифтом (размер шрифта задается прямо в разметке). Сами разметки я придумывать не буду - они должны реализовывать,как будут выглядеть айтемы для каждого вида.

Кастомный адаптер (простейший пример на основе `ArrayAdapter` - только важные для понимания части):

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private static final int TYPE_1 = 0; // идентификатор айтема первого типа
    private static final int TYPE_2 = 1; // идентификатор айтема второго типа
    private ArrayList mItems;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList items)
    {
        super(context, items);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mItems = items;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        // получаем идентификатор вида айтема в текущей позиции
        int type = getItemViewType(position); 
        View v = convertView;

        //инфлейтим разметку айтема для текущей позиции
        switch (type)
        {
            case TYPE_1:
                           v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_normal, null);
                           break;
            case TYPE_2:
                           v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_big, null);
                           break;
            default:

        }


//   Если айтемы разных видов содержат разные данные для отображения
//   то разделяем биндинг:
// 
//            switch (type)
//            {
//                case TYPE_1: // биндинг данных в айтем первого вида.
//                               
//                               break;
//                case TYPE_2: // биндинг данных в айтем второго вида.
//                               
//                               break;
//            }
//
// Так как в вашем случае данные в айтемах не меняются, то для обоих
// биндинг одинаковый и его не нужно разделять.

       String text = mItems.get(position); // извлекаем данные
       TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
       tv.setText(text); // размещаем в айтем

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
      // Здесь нужно определить вторую видимую позицию 
      // и вернуть идентификатор айтема второго типа
      // иначе - айтема первого типа
      // Надо подумать.
        return (twoPosition) ? TYPE_2 : TYPE_1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2; // два различных вида айтемов
    }

}
```

Поскольку в вашем случае внешний вид разных айтемов не отличается ни чем, кроме цвета и размера шрифта, то все эти отличия вы задаете непосредственно в разметке - биндить данные отдельно не требуется.
В более сложных случаях вы можете использовать любые независимые данные для разных видов айтемов, которые могут содержать абсолютно разные разметки и разделять их наполнение через `switch - case` в закоментированном блоке.

В реальном адаптере лучше использовать холдеры и прочие оптимизации

Comment: Сделал адаптер к списку. Правда, наследовался от BaseAdapter. Сейчас проблема в том, что не могу придумать как заставить один элемент как-бы быть на месте и в него только будет подставляться элемент списка. Это та проблема, про которую Вы писали комментариями "// Здесь нужно определить вторую видимую позицию 
      // и вернуть идентификатор айтема второго типа
      // иначе - айтема первого типа
      // Надо подумать." Возможно, у Вас есть какие-то идеи как это реализовать ?

Comment: Я вот сейчас подумал над вашей задачей и она поставленна изначально некорректно. Простой кастомизацией `ListView` ее не решить. Скорее всего, вам нужно реализовать что то по мотивам [этой библиотеки](https://github.com/DavidPizarro/PickerUI), только не со строками, а с айтемами.

Comment: А так, если продолжите "мучить" `ListView`, у него есть метод `getFirstVisiblePosition()`, который возвращает номер той позиции в адаптере, которая находится в первой видимой позиции списка. Со стороны адаптера это, по всей видимости, не реализовать и мой ответ нельзя считать правильным.

Comment: Еще [эту либу](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) можно поизучать. [Исходники на GitHub](https://github.com/maarek/android-wheel)