# Несколько разметок для айтемов в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня данный момент Список реализован с `Header` и `Footer`.

Код:

```
//Header objects
    bookDetailsObjects.setDate("16-янв-2105, 15:50");
    bookDetailsObjects.setFromTo("TSE - IST");
    bookDetailsObjects.setPNR("284TZ8");
    bookDetailsObjects.setValidUntil("03-Мар 2016 23:59");
    bookDetailsObjects.setRoute("Москва - Станбул");
    bookDetailsObjects.setDepartDate("25-Мар 2016 12:30");
    bookDetailsObjects.setFlightClass("Econom");
    bookDetailsObjects.setStatus(2);

    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.book_details_layout_item, listView, false);

    TextView mFromTo = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvFromTo);
    TextView mBookDate = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvBookDate);
    TextView mPNR = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvPNR);
    TextView mValidUntil = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.tvValidUntil);
    TextView mRoute = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.tvRoute);
    TextView mDepartDate = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.tvDepartDate);
    TextView mClass = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.tvClass);
    TextView mStatus = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

    mFromTo.setText(bookDetailsObjects.getFromTo());
    mBookDate.setText(bookDetailsObjects.getDate());
    mPNR.setText(bookDetailsObjects.getPNR());
    mValidUntil.setText(bookDetailsObjects.getValidUntil());
    mRoute.setText(bookDetailsObjects.getRoute());
    mDepartDate.setText(bookDetailsObjects.getDepartDate());
    mClass.setText(bookDetailsObjects.getFlightClass());

    switch(bookDetailsObjects.getStatus())
    {
        case 2:
            mStatus.setText(getString(R.string.status_canceled));
            break;
        case 0:
            mStatus.setText(getString(R.string.status_booked));
            break;
        case 1:
            mStatus.setText(getString(R.string.status_buyed));

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

 //End of Header Objects

 //Passengers objects

    passengersObjects.setPassGroup(0);
    passengersObjects.setName("Иванов Иван");
    passengersObjects.setBirthDate("14.01.1992");
    passengersObjects.setGender("Мужской");

    passengersObjects.setAdultTickPrice(15000);
    passengersObjects.setChildTickPrice(15000);
    passengersObjects.setInfTickPrice(15000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        passItems.add(passengersObjects);
    }

//End Passengers objects
//Footer objects

    bookDetailsObjects.setTotalPrice(45000);

    View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.book_layout_price_buttons, listView, false);

    TextView mTotalPrice = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalPrice);
    Button mCancel = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btnDetCancel);
    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ToastUtils.ToastShort(getApplicationContext(), "Отменено");
        }
    });
    Button mBuy = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btnDetBuy);
    mBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ToastUtils.ToastShort(getApplicationContext(), "Выкуплено");
        }
    });

    mTotalPrice.setText(bookDetailsObjects.getTotalPrice() + "РУБ");

    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    listView.addFooterView(footer);
    listView.setAdapter(new PassengersDetailAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.book_layout_pass_items, passItems));
}
```

**Адаптер:**

```
public class PassengersDetailAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PassengersObjects> {

private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
static Resources r;

public PassengersDetailAdapter(Context ctx, int rsc, List<PassengersObjects> objects) {
    super(ctx, rsc, objects);

    resource = rsc;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    PassengersObjects passengersObjects = getItem(position);

    TextView mName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);
    TextView mGender = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
    TextView mBirthDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBirthDate);
    TextView mTickPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTickPrice);

    mName.setText(passengersObjects.getName());
    mGender.setText(passengersObjects.getGender());
    mBirthDate.setText(passengersObjects.getBirthDate());

    switch(passengersObjects.getPassGroup())
    {
        case 0:
            mTickPrice.setText(passengersObjects.getAdultTickPrice() + "KZT");
            break;
        case 1:
            mTickPrice.setText(passengersObjects.getChildTickPrice() + "KZT");
            break;
        case 2:
            mTickPrice.setText(passengersObjects.getInfTickPrice() + "KZT");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**Выглядет так:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, так как мне нужно. Но мне нужно, чтобы они все были в одном адаптере `PassengersDetailAdapter`, и никак не могу понять как это реализовать, каша в голове. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Это делается через переопределение метода `getItemViewType()` адаптера. [Пример](http://learnncode.co/android/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/)

Comment: В вашем случае, когда в этот метод передается, что позиция на первом элементе, выводить хэдер, когда на последнем футер, для всех остальных - промежуточные айтемы.

Answer (score 1):

Не мучайтесь с `ListView`. Переделайте всё на `RecyclerView`. Там это делается [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510887/17609):

По позиции элемента определяем его тип и в зависимости от этого загружаем определённую разметку и отображаем её:

```
//метод, в коем вы должны в зависимости от позиции элемента возвращать
//её тип в виде числа, кое потом используется в onCreateViewHolder для загрузки разметки
//и в onBindViewHolder для наполнения её данными
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if (position == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
 }

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
    View itemLayoutView;

    //загружаем разметку в зависимости от типа и возвращаем
    //нужный холдер
    switch (viewType)
    {
        case 0:
            itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.zero_type_layout, parent, false);
            vh = new HolderZeroType(itemLayoutView);
            break;
        case 1:
            itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.first_type_layout, parent, false);
            vh = new HolderFirstType(itemLayoutView);
            break;
    }

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    switch (this.getItemViewType(position))
    {
        case 0:
           HolderZeroType zero = (HolderZeroType) holder;
           //наполняем данными разметку для нулевого типа
           break;
        case 1:
           HolderFirstType first = (HolderFirstType) holder;
           //наполняем данными разметку для нулевого типа
           break;
     }
 }

public static class HolderFirstType extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ...

    public ViewHolderText(View v)
    {
        super(v);
        ...
    }
}

public static class HolderZeroType extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ...

    public ViewHolderText(View v)
    {
        super(v);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: В `ListView` это делается практически [так же](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456472/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff, ИМХО в `RecyclerView` всё это удобнее) Ну и нет всяких плющек типа хедеров и не возникает ситуаций как в вопросе о том как их в адаптер перенести) И слушатели нажатий извне адаптера не назначить на элементы, что тоже избавляет от множества возможных проблем. Ну и без `ViewHolder` адаптер к `RecyclerView` не написать, что также избавляет от необходимости выяснять как это делается для `ListVeiw`. =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Извините, а как проверить последнюю позицию?

Comment: @Omuradil, длина списка с данными минус один...

Comment: давно тоже сталкивался с такими проблемами, реализовывал через RecyclerView, со временем "слепилась" обертка https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter