# ListView (чат) - разметка компонентов

Tags: android, xml, listview, chat

Доброго всем времени суток. У меня есть не большая проблема с разметкой ListView именно программным путём. Дело в том что я с сервера подгружаю сообщения, и, когда они загружаются я пытаюсь изменить гравитацию объектов, в зависимости от различия ID. В данном случае LinearLayout. В общем что я хочу....кода строится список в ListView, я хочу что моё сообщение было слева, а сообщение юзера выстраивалось по гравитации, с права. Сейчас покажу на скриншотах как я уже сделал. Может это не правильно? На рисунке первом, показано как Сообщения загрузились и список построился. Но если прокрутить ListView вниз и поднятся на верх, на рисунке втором видно, как (первые два) объекта потеряли гравитацию. Подскажите направление. За ранее спасибо :)

```
class ChatAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

        public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layoutUsersMsg);
            LinearLayout layoutBg = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layoutUsersMsgBg);
            layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lv_msg_styles));

            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_msg_user);
            TextView userText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);

            String myIDfromList = textView.getText().toString();

            if(!myIDfromList.equals(LV_USID)) { 
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                layoutBg.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_style_msg));
            } else {
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                layoutBg.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_style_msg));
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

ListView и построение адаптера

```
                        String msg = msgList.getString("msg");
                        String msg_id = msgList.getString("msg_id");
                        final String msg_id_us = msgList.getString("msg_id_user");

                        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        map.put(LV_MSGID, msg_id);
                        map.put(LV_MSG, msg);
                        map.put(LV_USID_MSG, msg_id_us);
                        data.add(map);
                    }

                    String[] from = { LV_MSGID, LV_MSG, LV_USID_MSG };
                    int   [] to   = { R.id.id_msg, R.id.msg, R.id.id_msg_user };

                    sAdapter = new ChatAdapter(FriendMsgActivity.this, data, R.layout.activity_friend_msg_adapter, from, to);
                    sList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvFriendMsg);
                    sList.setAdapter(sAdapter);
```

Рисунок номер 1

[image: Рисунок номер 1]

Рисунок номер 2

[image: Рисунок номер 2]

---

Вот получившийся на текущий момент адаптер:

```
class ChatAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

        public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            private LinearLayout layout;
            private LinearLayout layoutBg;
            private TextView textView;
            private TextView userText;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            //View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_msg_adapter, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.layout   = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutUsersMsg);
                viewHolder.layoutBg = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layoutUsersMsgBg);
                viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_msg_user);
                viewHolder.userText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            String myIDfromList = viewHolder.textView.getText().toString();
            viewHolder.layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lv_msg_styles));

            if(!myIDfromList.equals(LV_USID)) {
                viewHolder.layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                viewHolder.layoutBg.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_style_msg));
            } else {
                viewHolder.layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                viewHolder.layoutBg.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_style_msg));
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите любой ответ тут, на сайте про ListView и ViewHolder

Comment: Не понял вашего направления я.

Comment: Скорее всего дело в этой строке `View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` - Вам бы надо паттерн ViewHolder реализовать. Разметка элементов переиспользуется и в вашем случае подгрузилась широкая разметка и она попыталась преобразоваться к старому виду. Но неуспешно. ViewHolder, возможно, решит проблему

Comment: Переделал на ViewHolder, теперь у меня подставился шаблон `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_msg_adapter, parent, false);` из 7-ми строк, вместо моих сообщений. Т.е по факту список загрузился, но вместо сообщений, шаблонное наименование. Почему так?

Comment: Покажите в вопросе получившийся код

Comment: Вам не нужно динамически модифицировать `View`, вам нужно создать **две** разметки (для пользователя и собеседника), затем переопределить метод адаптера `getItemViewType()`, где определяется, какой тип разметки выводить в текущий айтем. Вариант реализации смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456472/177345). ViewHolder имеет другое назначение (кэширование ссылок на виджеты) и к решению именно вашей проблемы несколько далек.

Comment: pavlofff, помогите пожалуйста. Ничего не получается. Не могу понять какие именно действия нужно выполнить в `getItemViewType()`. На самом деле, я запутался в самой логики этой задачи. Я переопределил метод `getItemViewType()` в нём возвращаю `position`, далее в `getView()` я свитчем должен определить какой именно layout показать? Продемонстрируйте пример пожалуйста, если вам не трудно. Спасибо

Comment: sergei1094, вопрос задан уже давно, скажите вы нашли выход? Просто у меня сейчас такаяже проблема... немогу сделать розметку...