# ListView и Cursor Adapter android

Tags: android, listview, cursoradaper

Здравствуйте.
Заполняю ListView из адаптера.
По условию, меняю Layout эл-та списка.
При скроле списка, эл-ты перемешиваются, не могу понять, как это победить.

Код адаптера:

```
public class OrderAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
    }

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mitm_Name")));
        //holder.time.setText(cursor.getString(holder.timeIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup
            parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View v = null;

        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("State")) == 0) {

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cellordername, parent, false);
            holder.name    =   (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.txtmitmname);
        }
        else
        {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cellorder, parent, false);
            holder.name    =   (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.txtmitmname);
        }
        v.setTag(holder);
        return v;

    }

}
```

Переписал адаптер:

```
public Cursor getOrderData() {

    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM elf_Orders ORDER BY _id";
    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}

public class OrderAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
    }

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup
            parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("State")) == 0) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cellordername, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtmitmname);
            v.setTag(holder);
            holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mitm_Name")));
            return v;
        }
        else {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cellorder, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtmitmname);
            v.setTag(holder);
            holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mitm_Name")));
            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

Теперь разметки назначаются правильно, но вот данные выводятся в хаотичном порядке при скроле. В каком направлении копать?

Comment: Метод `newView(...)` предназначен для создания объекта `View`, но не для привязки данных к этому `View`. Привязкой данных к конкретному `View` занимается метод `bindView(...)`. Соответственно, Вам нужно перенести все эти Ваши `setText(...)` из `newView(...)` в `bindView(...)`. Это как минимум.

Comment: Я так сделал в первом варианте, там съезжает разметка. Во втором варианте с разметкой все ОК, но данные скачут как хотят.

Comment: Если все перенести в bindView, то данные при скроле отображаются правильно, но разметка присваивается на любые item. Замкнутый круг

Comment: Посмотрите как реализован адаптер [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8617766).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает. Только теперь надо научиться правильно обновлять список. Я делаю просто, присваиваю списку курсор, каждый раз при добавление чего-либо в базу. И у меня весь список начинается сначала, а надо красиво, в конец списка добавлять

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [`swapCursor(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#swapCursor(android.database.Cursor)).

Comment: И это, если у Вас все заработало, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, Ваш рабочий код в виде ответа, дабы эта тема была полезна не только Вам, но и другим людям, у которых возникнут похожие затруднения.

Comment: Да, swapcursor отчасти помог, список назад не листается, но и вперед тоже не пролистывается, т.е. новых эл-тов не видно. Получается только программно его пролистывать, при обновлении курсора?

Comment: По этому вопросу я вряд ли смогу Вам подсказать.

Answer (score 3):

Рабочий код адаптера:

```
public Cursor getOrderData() {

    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM elf_Orders ORDER BY _id";
    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}

public class OrderAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
    }

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("State"));
        if (type.equals("1")) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
        return getItemViewType(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mitm_Name")));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup
            parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View v = null;

        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("State")) == 0) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cellordername, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtmitmname);
        }
        else {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cellorder, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtmitmname);
        }

        v.setTag(holder);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Большое спасибо!

Comment: для чего нужен этот код?
    `@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }`

Comment: @zayn1991 этот метод возвращает количество различных типов айтемов в адаптере (в данном случае - 2 разных типа)

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо за ответ. Получается, это конкретно для его реализации используется метод?

Comment: @zayn1991 Методы адаптера `getViewTypeCount()` и `getItemViewType()` переопределяются, когда в списке необходимо реализовать [айтемы разного вида](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456472/177345).

Answer (score 0):

Так, на будущее.

**Если в Курсор адаптере заполняете if, то обязательно нужно заполнить else**, так как listview рандомно меняет сделанные изменения. Я тоже мучался, менял по id элемента цвет textView через if, прокручивал и при возврате был уже хаос. Потом мне подсказали заполнить else тем цветом, что должен быть по стандарту - помогло. Думаю, мой ответ кому-нибудь да поможет.

Код класса Adapter, меняющего цвет по id элемента:

```
package ru.diit.healthychildrenfree.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ru.diit.healthychildrenfree.R;


/**
 * Created by zaynulabid on 12.01.16.
 */
public class GroupAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public GroupAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
    super(context, cursor, 1);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent,false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView txName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameOfGrup); // инициализировали textView
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name_gruppi"));// достали строку в переменную
    txName.setText(name);// присвоили значение

    TextView tvOpisanieGruppi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewOpisanieGrup);
    String opisanieGruppi = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("opisanie_gruppi"));
    tvOpisanieGruppi.setText(opisanieGruppi);

    long idGroup = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_gruppi")); //нашли айди элемента с БД
    //Log.e("GAdapter", "bindView: idGroup = " + idGroup);
    if (idGroup == 11){ // если id = 11, меняем цвета текстов на те, что есть в файле colors
        //Log.e("GAdapter", "bindView: idGroup == 11\nзакрашиваем строчки");
        txName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorTitleFilled));
        tvOpisanieGruppi.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorTitleFilled));
    } else { // если не равен 11 (как раз этот блок не даст цветам меняться при прокрутке)
        txName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorTitle));
        tvOpisanieGruppi.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorTitle));
    }
}

}
```

Нет, я не считаю, что это решение правильное, но оно рабочее и при разработке простых задач в курсор-адаптере это решение легко использовать