# Android ListView смещение как в чатах

Tags: java, android, listview

Как можно в ListView сделать смещение влево и вправо на немного, чтобы эффект чата был?
Добавляю так:

```
   ChatMessageAdapter.ChatMessageViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.chat_message, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ChatMessageAdapter.ChatMessageViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else
        viewHolder = (ChatMessageAdapter.ChatMessageViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    final ChatMessage item = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.date.setText(item.getDate().toGMTString());
    viewHolder.message.setText(item.getMessage());
    viewHolder.topic.setText(item.getTopic());
    return convertView;
```

getLayoutParams запрашиваю, но там нет Gravity

Comment: Вам нужно создать две разметки, правосторонюю и левосторонюю. В адаптере переопределить метод `getItemViewType()`, который будет в зависимости от того, чье сообщение, ваше или собеседника выводить нужную разметку. [Пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456472/177345)