# Нарушена последовательность вывода в лист вью

Tags: java, android

столкнулся с интересной проблемой, я вывожу записи из БД в Лист Вью. Для наглядности, записи содержат цифры которые были добавлены в БД по очереди (1,2,3... 14). Вывожу их в лист вью и при прокручивании они как то рандомно меняют свой порядок, я просто кручу туда-сюда а строки как то меняются местами.

```
ArrayList<DialogSaveData> UpList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Вот такой код..

```
void loadOldMess(){

  UpList.clear();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("mess", null, "idto =? or idme = ?" , new String[]{idyou.replaceAll("\\s+",""),idyou.replaceAll("\\s+","")}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Загрузка сообщений", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        do {
            UpList.add(0, new DialogSaveData(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("idto")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("idto")),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data")),
                    savedText.replaceAll("\\s+",""),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("status"))

            ));

            // adapter = new CastomDialog(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);
            //присваиваем адаптер списку
           // chat.setAdapter(adapter);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Ничего нет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    //cursor.close();

}
```

адаптер присваиваю чуть чуть в другом месте

```
loadOldMess();



         adapter = new CastomDialog(ChatActivity.this, R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);
        //присваиваем адаптер списку
         chat.setAdapter(adapter);
```

код адаптера

```
public class CastomDialog extends ArrayAdapter<DialogSaveData> {
    ArrayList<DialogSaveData> products;
    Context context;
    int resorse;
    SharedPreferences sPref1;
    final String SAVED_PUB_KEY = "pub key";
    String decode, a;
    Animation anim = null;

    public CastomDialog(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<DialogSaveData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.products = products;
        this.context = context;
        this.resorse = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {



        if (convertView == null) {
            DialogSaveData product = getItem(position);
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (product.getTo().contains(product.getMyKey())){
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.castom_dialog_list, null, true);
                TextView data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mess);
                data.setText(product.getData());
                data.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (product.getStatus().contains("1")){
                    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.new_mass);
                    data.startAnimation(anim);
                }


            }else{
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.castom_dialog_list_right, null, true);
                TextView data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mess1);
                data.setText(product.getData());
                data.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            }
        }



       // TextView me = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
       // me.setText(product.getMe());




        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема в адаптере - покажите код создания вью-элемента и вставки данных.

Comment: обновил код в вопросе

Comment: Я имел ввиду код адаптера, где создаётся вью для элемента списка и вставляются туда данные

Comment: тупанул, добавил код кастомного адаптера

Comment: Для случая `convertView != null` надо вью новыми данными заполнять, они же reusable.

Comment: A, ну я просто убрал это условие, спасибо

Comment: У Вас в списке два типа элементов - думаю будут проблемы несоответствия пришедшего с требуемым . Посмотрите как это делается правильно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456472/11515